# how to get animated zooming and pan with openlayers?

Tags: openlayers

Like website:http://www.tomtom.com/livetraffic/

When I try pan or zoom on the above site, feels very good similar to Google map, it's very smoothly for this user experience.

my question is how I can implement this effect with openlayers respectively for pan and zoom?
I could not find them in openlayers examples at least.

thanks for you attention.

following is part of my source code, maybe it works but not smoothly as I think

> ```
>         var map, layer; 
>         function init() {
>             var options = { 
>                 projection: "EPSG:900913",
>
>                 maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(18.203001,
> ```
>
> 47.078001, 399.909001, 261.796001),
>
> ```
>                 scales: [2400, 1200, 600, 300, 150],
>                 units: "m",
>
>                 panDuration: 100,
>                 controls: [new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(
>         {dragPanOptions: {enableKinetic: true}}
>     )]
>              var tile = new SimpleTileCache("map",
> ```
>
> "tilecache/8f/",
>                    {
>                        'format': 'image/png',
>                        transitionEffect: 'resize'
>                    });
>
> ```
>              map.addLayers([tile]);
> ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Effect is called as **transitionEffect**
You can implement this effect to your code by changing layers property.
I suppose you have a WMS or TMS layer.

```
 var tiled_resize_effect = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
     "WMS tiled resize", 
     "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?",
     {layers: 'basic'}, 
     {transitionEffect: 'resize'}
 );
```

Check these examples

[WMS Transition](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/transition.html) 
[Google Transition](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/google-v3.html)

Best Regards

Comment: Hi Myra, thanks for your answer, and I have tried your advice and listed examples above, WMS Transition is what I like. I'm using TileCache, seems not working with resize. More, I find [line](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/emanuel/animatedZooming/demo.html), but there is no word like resize in its source code, why aslo has that good effect?

Comment: It also works with TMS,if you can share your code I may help.

Comment: Not so necessary,TileCache constructor has 4 arguments in which transitionEffect is placed 4th parameter in options.That should be something like,new OpenLayers.Layer.TileCache("Map","tilecache/8f","layername",{ ..options.. });

You've setting options parameter in third one.Check this out

Comment: Thanks Myra, I make a mistake on TileCache usage, it works after I correct it

Answer (score 3):

For panning, that’s what’s called kinetic dragging, see:
http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/kinetic.html

Comment: Thanks.Yes, I tried that and take it into my code, and works well.

Comment: Provided link is dead.